# Stop table elements from shifting position when hovering?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-transitions

So I have a table with two rows. One more images, one for a paragraph underneath. The images link to different web pages, and I have an animation where the border grows and changes color but I don't want the image to move position when it hovers. Any way can I prevent the image from doing this?

```css
.project-table img {
  border: 6px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-table img:hover {
  border: 12px solid #FF1D58;
}

td {
  padding: 0px 180px 0 0;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="project-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://thebenlusted.github.io/jsauthentication/" target="_blank" title="JavaScript Authenticator"><img src="images/js-auth-screenshot.png"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" title="FrickIt Studios Website"><img src="images/sigma-site-screenshot.png"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this lame height difference.
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this lame height difference.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `box-shadow` instead of `border`

```css
.project-table img {
  border:6px solid white;
  width:300px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.project-table img:hover {
 border-color: #FF1D58;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 29, 88, 1);
  
}
td {
  padding: 0px 180px 0 0;
  width:110px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table class="project-table">
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://thebenlusted.github.io/jsauthentication/" target="_blank" title="JavaScript Authenticator"><img src="images/js-auth-screenshot.png"></a></td>
              <td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" title="FrickIt Studios Website"><img src="images/sigma-site-screenshot.png"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is
                on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this
                lame height difference.
              </p></td>
              <td>
                <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is
                  on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this
                  lame height difference.
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you **increase width of border**, But you can same do this with same affect by using `css` property `box-shadow`.

```css
.project-table img {
  border: 6px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-table img:hover {
  border-color: #FF1D58;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 29, 88, 1);
}

td {
  padding: 0px 180px 0 0;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="project-table">
            <tr>
              <td><a href="https://thebenlusted.github.io/jsauthentication/" target="_blank" title="JavaScript Authenticator"><img src="images/js-auth-screenshot.png"></a></td>
              <td><a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" title="FrickIt Studios Website"><img src="images/sigma-site-screenshot.png"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is
                on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this
                lame height difference.
              </p></td>
              <td>
                <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is
                  on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this
                  lame height difference.
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep same border width with and without hovering.

```css
.project-table img {
  border: 12px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.project-table img:hover {
  border: 12px solid #FF1D58;
}

td {
  padding: 0px 180px 0 0;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="project-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://thebenlusted.github.io/jsauthentication/" target="_blank" title="JavaScript Authenticator"><img src="images/js-auth-screenshot.png"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank" title="FrickIt Studios Website"><img src="images/sigma-site-screenshot.png"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this lame height difference.
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Hello? This is a paragraph. I am trying to see what the width and height is on this element. If we keep the paragraphs at the same length then we won't have this lame height difference.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```